# Genshi: Can't access imported modules from directives in HTML

Tags: python, genshi

**Background:** I'm using Genshi to generate HTML reports.

```
import genshi
import os
from genshi.template import MarkupTemplate

files = [
    r"a\b\c.txt",
    r"d/e/f.txt",
]

html = '''
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/">
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p py:for="f in sorted(files, key=lambda x: x.lower().split(os.path.sep))">
                ${f}
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
'''
template = MarkupTemplate(html)
stream = template.generate(
    files = files
)
print(stream.render('html'))
```

**Problem:** Genshi throws an UndefinedError exception because it doesn't know about modules I've imported.

```
D:\SVN\OSI_SVT\0.0.0.0_swr65430\srcPy\OSI_SVT>python36 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(stream.render('html'))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\genshi\core.py", line 184, in render
    return encode(generator, method=method, encoding=encoding, out=out)
  ...
genshi.template.eval.UndefinedError: "os" not defined
```

**Question:** Is there some way to make Genshi automatically aware of imported modules?

If this isn't possible natively in Genshi, I'd accept an answer that programmatically creates a collection of modules have been imported so they can be passed to the `generate()` call.  For example: `generate(**args)`

**What I've tried:**

- Read the [genshi documentation](https://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation).
- Searched StackOverflow.  No dice.
- Adding `os = os` to the `template.generate()` call.  This does work, but it is annoying and error-prone to have to duplicate my imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this outside of Genshi.  This approach adds all global and local objects (imports as well as global and local variables) and adds them to a dictionary.  The dictionary is then passed to `generate()` as keyword args (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/3508142) if you aren't familiar with this).

```
import genshi
import os
import types
from genshi.template import MarkupTemplate

html = '''
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/">
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p py:for="f in sorted(files, key=lambda x: x.lower().split(os.path.sep))">
                ${f}
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
'''

def main():

    files = [
        r"a\b\c.txt",
        r"d/e/f.txt",
    ]

    generation_args = {}
    for scope in [globals(), locals()]:
        for name, value in scope.items():
            generation_args[name] = value

    template = MarkupTemplate(html)
    stream = template.generate(**generation_args)

    print(stream.render('html'))

main()
```